# Angular hash in facebook api redirect_uri

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, url-routing, facebook-login, loopbackjs

Hi I have following situation:

Backend: Loopback/nodejs service

Frontend: Angular >=2

And i wana perform login via facebook. But there is problem - when i sent below request by angular http provider:

```
GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890123456&redirect_uri=http://my-domain.com/#/login?type=fb
```

the request which actually go out from web browser is:

```
GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890123456&redirect_uri=http://my-domain.com/
```

So the browser or http provider cut off everything after hash '#'. I try to change this character to it's escape sequence `# = %23` but when facebook redirect to this site this code was not change to # so the server cannot find url `my-domain.com/%23/login...`.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I try to remove '#' from angular routing but after that, the backend have problem with links like `my-domain.com/login` because this link works only on angular application but not in node.js server - so server fail.

So i found other solution - first - remove '#' from angular http request - so send following request to fb:

```
GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890123456&redirect_uri=http://my-domain.com/login?type=fb
```

And then in backend just implement redirection for one link:

```
my-domain.com/login -> my-domain.com/#/login
```

So in loopback nodejs server we redirect login without hash to login with hash and thats all - nothing more to change :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to note if someone comes here:

as of August 2018, the # -> %23 trick works and Facebook correctly redirects the browser back to the wanted URL that actually includes #.

Comment: That's fine of course! I only described the outcome :-)